# Not sure how to properly use a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I read a lot of questions here on stacoverflow, but it is still not clear to me how should I use a partialview within a main view with an action method. What's probably wrong is my aproach in general. With what I have so far I am not sure how to continue with my code.

I will start with the main view :

```
 @{
        ViewBag.Title = "getRolesByYear";
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        getRolesForYear(parseInt(@DateTime.Now.Year));

        $(function () {
            $('#years a').click(function () {
                var year = $(this).text();
                console.log(year);
                getRolesForYear(parseInt(year));
            });
        })
        //console.log(year);


        function getRolesForYear(year) {
            console.log(year);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("getRolesByYear", "WorkRoles")',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    year: year
                },
                success: successFunc,
                error: errorFunc
            });

            function successFunc(data, status) {
                console.log('x');
                }

            }

            function errorFunc() {
                alert('error');
            }
        }



    </script>

    <div id = "years" class="btn-group btn-group-justified timeline">
        <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.Year</a>
        <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year</a>
        <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year</a>
    </div>

<div id"partial"></div>
```

In this view I have three buttons with different year for each button. On page load or on button click I make an ajax call to an `action method` with the an `int` year as a parameter.

This is a simplified version of my action method :

```
public ActionResult getRolesByYear(int year)
    {


      // a couple of queries here


        var list = list of RoleViewModel objects;

        return PartialView(list);
```

And here is the partialView :

```
@model IEnumerable<eksp.Models.RoleViewModel>


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>item.Role.RoleName</h2>

        <h1> item.Role.RoleDescription</h1>
        <p class="lead">Focus start : item.Role.FocusStart</p>
        <p>Focus end : item.Role.FocusStart </p>

    </div>
}
```

Obviously, a lot of thins aren't clear to me. How can I use this partial view with the action method i have and the main view? Do I need a separate method for the partial view? Any tips?

Comment: what are your requirements (user use case). Use technology as needed based on your usecases. What is your expected behavior from a usre's point of view.

Comment: i just need to display the list of objects,  which i have in the action method in the main view via a partial view. P.S I added the partial view.

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax call will invoke the action method which returns the partial view result (markup generated by executing the partial view). I guess you simply need to use the response of the ajax call to update your DOM.

If you want to update the content of the div with id partial with the response, you can do that in the `success` event handler of your ajax call.

```
success : function(response)
{
  $("#partial").html(response);
}
```

I would also recommend to call the `getRolesForYear` method on document ready event.

```
$(function () {

       getRolesForYear(parseInt(@DateTime.Now.Year));

        $('#years a').click(function () {
            var year = $(this).text();
            console.log(year);
            getRolesForYear(parseInt(year));
        });
})
```

Also, If your main view is also the result of action method `getRolesByYear`, you probably want to return the partial view result only on the ajax call, the other calls,you can return the partial view

```
public ActionResult getRolesByYear(int year)
{
    var list = list of RoleViewModel objects;
    if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
       return PartialView(list);
    }
    else
    {
      return View(list);
    }
}
```

Here the same action method handles the request for main view and ajax call. It returns the same view for ajax call, but using PartialView call, so layout will be ignored. But If you have a specific view you want to return, you can do that as well.

```
if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    return PartialView("_yearlyRoles",list);
}
```

Comment: This ajax call is beein invoked in the view for the action method. My partialview doesn't have an action method. Is this a problem? Thanks for you answer.

Comment: `getRolesByYear` action method returns the partial view, which is being called from your main views js code

Comment: my main view is called getRolesByYear.cshtml, the action method is also called getRolesByYear. The partial view is called _yearlyRoles.

Comment: thank for your asnwer. I did what you suggested(except the first suggestion, this one i got from the other asnwer). Currently when on F5 i get the alert 'error'. Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: check the browser network tooks->network tab and find out the ajax call and see what the response is. Looks like it is not a 200 OK response (which happens when everything goes good). Looks like your server code is failing. You can right click on the network call and select "Open in new window" to see whether your page is returning the expected result or an error.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons I like using partial views for rendering data via Ajax calls. For example if I want to start searching in order to avoid the server call i Just use an ajax call to the controller which returns the search results through a partial view. In your example yoy need to load the results in partial div.

```
function successFunc(data, status) {
     $("#partial").html(data);
}
```